# How do I approach the following problem in python?

Tags: python

In my recent exams I had the following problem, and I didn't even know where to start. Any help will be appriciated:

> Let's suppose that python does not have "set" and "dict" functions. Write a class named "IntSet" for sets with integrals as data and the right methods so that the program does the following:

[image: program]

I'm really sorry if I translated it wrong, English is not my native language. Thank you in advance for any help given.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework. Post the code you already tried at least if you seek help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem requires knowledge about Object oriented programming. You need to create a class named 'IntSet' which has methods 'new_element', 'symmetric_difference', 'has_element', 'delete_element' and 'union' with required functionalities. I recommended you follow some tutorials on python classes and objects.

Following links may be useful;

[Python Object Oriented Programming](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/object-oriented-programming)

[Python Classes and Objects](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/)